# file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/index.php?get=x'); how to make it work?

Tags: php

On my local host i wanna test my API, put every time i use the statement :

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/index.php?get=x');
```

the script stops with " timeout ", while the URL up there works fine when requested the normal way !.

Hint: i think it have something to do with the php.ini file !?

secondly, using cURL, (`file_get_contents`+`stream_creat_content`), would be faster ?, i needed it to respond very fast

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you calling the file_get_content in your index.php?

Comment: NO, in another file off course :)

Comment: Does curl work in the way file_get_contents should have? Have you tried calling the url of your api on the same host on a shell with command line curl?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a firewall issue than to do with php.ini.

The fastest way to do this, however, will always be a direct `include()` to a file path. It would probably require some re-working of the API (because you shouldn't set `$_GET` variables programmatically), but saves a ton of overhead. If you need this in production, it's most likely worth making the changes.